# How to install 'cdfs' kernel module?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, software-installation, cd

I am unable copy files from 'mpegav' within video CDs in my Ubuntu 14.04.
After a extended search now I understand I need to mount the cd using 'cdfs':

```
sudo mount -t cdfs -o ro /dev/sr0 /media/data/cd
```

but I get error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'cdfs'
```

So decided to install cdfs module:

```
sudo module-assistant get cdfs
```

It show this message:

[image]

Where from I will get cdfs source?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried `mount -t iso9660 ` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [cdfs-src](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/cdfs-src) package is [deprecated](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=718966) (reason: doesn't work with linux 3.1 or later) since Ubuntu 13.04, you won't find a repo to install it for 14.04.

Since ISO 9660 is also known as CDFS (Compact Disc File System), I would try as suggested by [Archemar](https://askubuntu.com/users/323295/archemar) to mount your video CD with:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/sr0 /media/data/cd
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660

Comment: +1 for researching why it was removed from the repos :)

Comment: Mounting worked as my question, still unable to copy files from video CD directly. I could copy video files using `vcdxrip`.